# MySQL join query for two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two database tables.  We'll refer to the first as ItemInfo and the other as ItemStatus.  Info is the larger of the two, and Status is created using only active products listed under Info (where Active = 1).  Only two columns are shared between Info and Status, those being ListID and QtyOnHand.

The problem with Status is that even though all active items have been recorded, not all of them have proper web IDs, which is under the column in ItemInfo labeled "WebID."  Items without proper IDs are just given an ID of 0.

What I want to do is perform a join between the two, but I'm not sure which to use.  I initially thought a right join would be correct.  I need every column from ItemStatus (since it contains statistics that are calculated and inserted by a script) but only those records that have valid web IDs.  I know the query will look something like this:

```
SELECT A.*, B.WebID FROM ItemStatus A
(?) JOIN ItemInfo B
ON A.ListID = B.ListID
WHERE B.WebID > 0
```

The idea is there, but I'm not sure how to express it.  The Status table doesn't have the WebIDs because when I initially constructed it, I felt having it as a column would be redundant.  The reason we needed QtyOnHand was because it's calculated in a way that's different from what's done for ItemInfo.

How can I fix this query?

Comment: You're only taking `WebID` from B so you just need `JOIN` - meaning an inner join.

Comment: I think that did it.  I just need to verify that the web IDs are mapped correctly.

Comment: I'd better write a proper answer then!

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.  It helps having phpMyAdmin so I can test things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only taking `WebID` from B so you just need `JOIN` - meaning an inner join;

```
SELECT A.*, B.WebID FROM ItemStatus A
JOIN ItemInfo B
ON A.ListID = B.ListID
WHERE B.WebID > 0
```

It joins all the rows from one table to the rows from the other, then applies the `WHERE` condition. So therefore returning you the desired rows with a positive `WebID`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think You need Right join

```
SELECT A.*, B.WebID FROM ItemStatus A
LEFT JOIN ItemInfo B
ON A.ListID = B.ListID
WHERE B.WebID > 0
```

Comment: I think you got them mixed up.  I need everything from ItemStatus, not ItemInfo.  I checked to see if doing what I need to will give me any results in the ItemInfo table (the bigger of the two, but I don't need everything from it) and there are some active items that don't have correct WebIDs.  The ListIDs in Status will be compared with the ones in Info, and depending on which of those have WebIDs > 0 (we know they're active because Status only has active items), the query will produce a table of all columns from Status and only WebID from Info.